# Two different definition of strip method in Python (2.7.14rc1) official documentation? str.strip([chars]) vs string.strip(s[, chars])

Tags: python, string, strip

When I search the strip method for a string in Python (2.7.14rc1) official documentation, I found out there are two definitions. That is `str.strip([chars])` and `string.strip(s[, chars])`

My question is: What are the differences between the two definitions? Which one should I follow?

`str.strip([chars])` is in 5. Built-in Types section: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

`string.strip(s[, chars])` is in 7. String Services section:https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no functional differences between the two methods aside from the fact that `string.strip()` requires an extra import (`import string`) to be called.

In addition, `string.strip()` is not included in Python 3, and `.strip()` (the method that acts directly on the str object) is seen more often compared to `string.strip()`.

Other than that, you are free to use whichever you would like to use.

Comment: Oh! To use `string.strip(s[, chars])`, we use to first `import string`. Then the `strip(s[, chars])` method is applied to the first argument `s`. And in Python 3, no string.py are included and we just directly apply strip method to built in [str](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) type

Comment: @banghuazhao Yep, but in Python 3 `string.py` still exists - it's just that they got rid of the `string.strip()` method. :)

Answer (score 0):

As `strip()` is available as a method on the built-in [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) type, you can just use that without importing the `string` module.

And if you look into the [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/string.py#L250), you can see that `string.strip()` still uses `str.strip()` under the hood.